# fix sql query. i want print output in 1 row but in my query return 6 row i want combine as image

Tags: php, sql, error-handling

**Query is**

```
SELECT unf_employee.employee_code,unf_employee.name AS Employee_Name, unf_attendances.payable_amount, unf_processed_salary_heads.type, unf_processed_salary_heads.name AS title, unf_processed_salary_heads.amount 
FROM unf_attendances 
INNER JOIN unf_attendances_unf_processed_salary_heads_c ON UNF_Attendances.id = unf_attendances_unf_processed_salary_heads_c.unf_attendances_unf_processed_salary_headsunf_attendances_ida 
INNER JOIN unf_processed_salary_heads ON unf_attendances_unf_processed_salary_heads_c.unf_attend5f51y_heads_idb = unf_processed_salary_heads.id 
INNER JOIN unf_employee ON unf_attendances.unf_employee_id_c = unf_employee.id 
WHERE unf_attendances.deleted = 0
```

[image: Query]

**-----OUTPUT-------**

[image: Output]

**i want print output as  following table**

[image: expected output]

please fix my sql query and print table as follow that image.

Comment: Add all information as text not as image

Comment: add group by `employee_code` and use `SUM` for different price columns and `CONCAT` for `string` columns. (In case you want `type` show `Earning,deduction`)

Comment: Another option is to learn about pivot queries

Answer (score 0):

```
Check this query, it might need some minimal modifications.
```

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_CODE,
       EMPLOYEE_NAME,
       ['BASIC'],
       ['HRA'],
       ['EXTRA'],
       ['UNIFORM ALLOWANCE'],
       ['PF'],
       ['ESIC'],
       (['BASIC'] + ['HRA'] + ['EXTRA'] + ['UNIFORM ALLOWANCE'] + ['PF'] + ['ESIC']) - PAYABLE_AMOUNT AS TOTAL_DEDUCTIONS,
       PAYABLE_AMOUNT AS NET_PAID
FROM
    (SELECT UNF_EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_CODE,
            UNF_EMPLOYEE.NAME AS EMPLOYEE_NAME,
            UNF_ATTENDANCES.PAYABLE_AMOUNT,
            UNF_PROCESSED_SALARY_HEADS.TYPE,
            UNF_PROCESSED_SALARY_HEADS.NAME AS TITLE,
            UNF_PROCESSED_SALARY_HEADS.AMOUNT
        FROM UNF_ATTENDANCES
        INNER JOIN UNF_ATTENDANCES_UNF_PROCESSED_SALARY_HEADS_C ON UNF_ATTENDANCES.ID = UNF_ATTENDANCES_UNF_PROCESSED_SALARY_HEADS_C.UNF_ATTENDANCES_UNF_PROCESSED_SALARY_HEADSUNF_ATTENDANCES_IDA
        INNER JOIN UNF_PROCESSED_SALARY_HEADS ON UNF_ATTENDANCES_UNF_PROCESSED_SALARY_HEADS_C.UNF_ATTEND5F51Y_HEADS_IDB = UNF_PROCESSED_SALARY_HEADS.ID
        INNER JOIN UNF_EMPLOYEE ON UNF_ATTENDANCES.UNF_EMPLOYEE_ID_C = UNF_EMPLOYEE.ID
        WHERE UNF_ATTENDANCES.DELETED = 0 ) 
PIVOT (SUM(AMOUNT)
       FOR TITLE IN (['BASIC'],
                     ['HRA'],
                     ['EXTRA'],
                     ['UNIFORM ALLOWANCE'],
                     ['PF'],
                     ['ESIC']));
```